# how to make vim handle 64bit int number?

Tags: vim

in vim `:h Number`:

> Number        A 32 or 64 bit signed number.

the value of max 32/64bit number:

```
2^31=2147483648
2^63=9223372036854775808
```

Now if I call `str2nr()` in vim:

```
:echo str2nr('2147483648')
-> -2147483648


:echo str2nr('112147483648')
-> 478333952
```

or eval the expression directly:

```
echo 2147483648 + 7777
-> -2147482871
```

So the question is, vim doc tells `number` is 32 or 64 bit number. How to make vim handle the 64bit number? like `2147483648 + 7777 =2147491425`

P.S above test was done on:

```
Archlinux 64bit
Vim 7.4.135 (from Arch 64bit repo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/2pXdRG7yW0Y. You can't.

Bram says that a number is an `int` and if your platform declares int as having 64 bits you will have a 64 bit int in vim. However int was chosen to be 32 bits (by your compiler), so you only get 32 bits for a number.

In `:h limits` I find the following.

```
Range of a Number variable:  -2147483648 to 2147483647 (might be more on 64
                           bit systems)
```

The might be more is probably telling you that those limits might still be the same on a 64 bit platform. It is totally up to the compiler.

I think the only way you would be able to change this is if you were to go through all of the source code and change how numbers are represented internally or find a compiler that represents `int` as 64 bits. (I don't know of one off hand)

If you want to find out how many bits your compiler will represent an `int` as you can run the following code.

```
#include "limits.h"
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
    printf("sizeof int in bits %lu\n", sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
}
```

On my 64 bit machine this prints (I suspect your machine will do the same)

```
sizeof int in bits 32
```

Comment: `Linux LsyHP 3.13.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 7 22:47:48 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux` this is the output of `uname -a`, it is a 64bit box.

Comment: I do google a lot, but didn't find the thread you posted in your answer.  It seems that we cannot do that, since Bram has already confirmed.  If I work on a plugin, it doesn't make sense if I change the codes and compile a specific version of vim as test/dev env....

Comment: @Kent Being a 64 bit system does not guarantee that your compiler will use 64 bits for an int. I added some code you could use to compile on your system to see how many bits your compiler will use for an int. I believe arch uses `gcc` and gcc should print that it is using 32 bits for an int.

Comment: you are right. I post the comment was for the 1st revision of your answer. There you mentioned a 64bit system could have "more". In last comment I explained why I won't change the codes and compile my own vim.  but your link is very helpful, I think I should accept this answer.